# UIDatePicker adding one to year

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I have a very strange and confusing problem. I can't find anything about it and it seems like a bug with Apple, but if anyone has a suggestion on how to get around this it would be helpful.
There are certain dates that are adding 1 to the year with a UIDatePicker, seems to never be less than December 27th. I've went back a few years to try and find a pattern. Here are some examples:

```
Any date picked >= December 28th in 2014 changes to 2015
>= 29th in 2013 -> 2014
>= 30th in 2012 -> 2013
2011 (issue doesn't occur)
>= 26th in 2010 -> 2011
>= 27th in 2009 -> 2010
>= 28th in 2008 -> 2009
>= 30th in 2007 -> 2008
=  31st in 2006 -> 2007
2005  (issue doesn't occur)
>= 26th in 2004 -> 2005
>= 28th in 2003 -> 2004
>= 29th in 2002 -> 2003
>= 30th in 2001 -> 2002
=  31st in 2000 -> 2001
=  31st in 1999 -> 2000
>= 27th in 1998 -> 1999
>= 28th in 1997 -> 1998
>= 29th in 1996 -> 1997
=  31st in 1995 -> 1996
1994  (issue doesn't occur)
```

Hopefully that's not too confusing. I can't seem to find a definitive pattern and can't figure out how to get around this issue. Here is the code I'm using to retrieve the date from the picker:

```
NSString *date;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd"];
date = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use YYYY, use yyyy.

Comment: @Anna It looks like that was the issue, what a dumb mistake. I always thought they were the same. If you post as an answer I will choose it. Thanks

Comment: Actually, there are several posts already on SO regarding this annoying format difference.  Feel free to accept Pierre's answer.  See http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns for details.

Comment: That's a helpful page, Ive been looking for a resource like that, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don´t know if it would change anything but you could try

`[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd"];`

Comment: because `YYYY` stands for the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601) calendar, that consists of complete weeks. as 365 mod 7 == 1, the start of each new year varies, and a year is either 52 or 53 weeks long. Therefor the Jan 1st, 2nd, 3rd can belong to the old year, but also, Dec, 29th, 30th, 31st can already belong to the next year. Or differently said: if the natural  calendar's last week's Thursday is 31st of Dec or before, the week belongs to the last week of the Year of Week calendar. If it fails on Jan, 1st, that whole week belongs to the new year in the week calendar.

Answer (score 1):

In NSDateFormatter, "Y" and "y" specify different kinds of year that may start on different days. You want "y".

From the [NSDateFormatter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1):

> A common mistake is to use YYYY. yyyy specifies the calendar year
>   whereas YYYY specifies the year (of “Week of Year”), used in the ISO
>   year-week calendar. In most cases, yyyy and YYYY yield the same
>   number, however they may be different. Typically you should use the
>   calendar year.

Comment: Thank you, I had actually found that after Anna pointed out I should be using yyyy.